# Multiple MVC repositories based on user roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, repository, roles

I am building an MVC (Microsoft) application that uses repository to access data.

I have a requirement where based on user role, you may or may not have access to certain pieces of data, or certain rows within a data table that contain flags or values.

Basically I need to customize the data coming back from the repository based on role.

What do you suggest?

1) Create a 'public' and a 'private' concrete repository from the same IRepository and customize the logic in each, then intantiate at the controller based on role membership.

2) Create private methods inside my one repository and choose the correct one based on the public/private role membership.

3) Other?

Thanks.

Comment: IMO it's little bit broad and opinion based for SO but...I'd go with #2 (even if formally I'd prefer #1) because it makes easy to move such logic outside code. I'm thinking about a DB table or a configuration file with parsed/parseable expressions...

Comment: IMO best solution is to put the rolebased logic as close to the db as possible (in the db if possible), hence one repository that handles the logic. You should then be able to build one repository that handles all logic.

Answer (score 0):

**Other**

[Make it data driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming), or you will end up in a word of pain.
Roles tend to grow
**Update**
Create table that maps roles to properties use flags if there's more to property-role relationship than can/cannot, then create [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) that can produce objects based on input from that table, then [define interface,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computing%29) and create control mechanism for handling these role based properties.
 Yeah now it sounds somewhat complicated. :)

Comment: Care to explain more? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A repository by definition does CRUD, there should not be logic in it (from what I know).

The queries that hit your repository should deal with not retrieving X information since your user Y doesn't have the right to see it.

If you keep business logic out of your repository you will find it much easier to maintain.

Edit : It's just an opinion, I'm far from an all-knowing mighty Jon Skeet ;)